# Include a text or XML file via the script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

For a little context I'm working on a site for a client and it has to run completely offline. It's just a set of html/css/js files that you run locally. The computers it will be used on are office computers and quite locked down so I can't even use java. Luckily the project isn't overly complicated and I've accomplished most of my goals with this limited platform. The issue I'm having is I want to create some easy to change files to load the data from. Right now I have all the data loading through script tags that point to js files that can be manually edited, however I've tried to make the javascript as simple and straight forward as I can but it's still not looking very friendly to someone who hasn't programmed before.

What I would like to do is include an xml file or text file in the HTML using a script tag or something similar and then use JS to read the contents but every time I try this it doesn't actually load the file. Here's a few things I've tried:

```
<script type="text/xml" src="myxml.xml"></script>
<script type="text/plain" src="myxml.xml"></script>
```

I've tried using XMLHttpRequest but most of these attempts end in the same result.. can't do a cross-site request. Even though I'm using a url "myxml.xml" and they're in the same folder, chrome is still convinced this is a XSS attempt. So I'm starting to run out of ideas. Can anyone think of any clever way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

IF you're **goal** is to just run your `web-app`, even *offline* and you do not care about cross-browser compatibility, you can consider to convert you're application to [Packaged App](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html).

It will work only in `google-chrome` browser but setting the right permissions, you should not have problem with cross-site requests. At this point, you could download the xml content through a noraml `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: The problem with that is most of the computers use IE, with some running Chrome, and it has to be able to run out of the package with no prior configuration and no changes to the browsers. So I can't create it as a chrome extension, nor can I rely on ActiveX.

Comment: `IE` will not complain if you make `cross-site` requests... but you still need `ActiveX`...

Comment: So there's no way that you know of to convince browsers to load files other than .js files using the script tag? Or any tag for that matter? I just need it to load the content into DOM so I can process it with JS.